# #thing1:hover #thing2 {} not working?

Tags: html, css, hover

I need some help with CSS, I'm trying to make it so when the mouse is hovering over #konnichiwa, it displays #konnichiwab. When changing things using #konnichiwa:hover and #konnichiwab:hover, it works, it's just the selecting other ids that has trouble.
**edit: Sorry, I forgot to mention, I've tried the "+" selector as well. Still no luck.**

**Second edit: from what I understand, the sibling selector is to select the element next to the selected in code? I've edited out a few lines in this question, I apologise. Konnichiwa and konnichiwab aren't next to each other. This is because I've placed konnichiwa in a div for styling, and I don't want to apply this styling to konnichiwab. I probably could solve the issue by deleting the div and adding a class to konnichiwa, but I would first like to see if there is another solution that doesn't require them to be next to each other.**

```
<span id="konnichiwa">こんにちは</span>

<div class="tbubs" id="konnichiwab">Hello</div>

#konnichiwa:hover + #konnichiwab {
    color: blue;
    display:block;
}

.tbubs 
{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 115px;
    margin-left: 35px;
    background-color:#ea3030;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-left: 30px;
}

.tbubs:after 
{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -15px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 15px 10px 0;
    border-color: #ea3030 transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.tbubs:after 
{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -15px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 15px 10px 0;
    border-color: #ea3030 transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: For that selector to work as expected `#konnichiwab` should be *inside* `#konnichiwa`. Currently they are siblings.

Comment: A space is a descendent combinator, perhaps you want to use the adjacent sibling combinator: `+` instead of space. http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/combinators

Comment: In regards to your second edit, no, there is absolutely no way you can get a hover event to bubble out of an elements parent and affect some other random element on the page using CSS alone. The closest you can do is siblings.

Answer (score 1):

For that selector to work as expected `#konnichiwab` should be *inside* `#konnichiwa`. Currently they are siblings.

You can use the **[adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)** to work around this.

```
#konnichiwa:hover + #konnichiwab {
    color: blue;
    display:block;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/X98tE/

Answer (score 0):

Use can use adjacent sibling combinator (+) . So whenever you hover on first selector, properties will be applied to second selector i.e its adjacent .

```
#konnichiwa:hover + #konnichiwab {
    color: blue;
    display:block;
}
```

Please read this [adjacent sibling combinator](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/adjacent-sibling/)

Answer (score 0):

Others are suggesting the `adjacent sibling selector` (for good reason - it could work depending on your mark up...)

Something like http://jsfiddle.net/KaHP5/1/

However, I would like to suggest an alternative: the `general sibling selector`. It's CSS3, so IE support is a concern (primarily IE 7 and 8 are buggy - but they do work... [Reference](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/generalsiblingselector))

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KaHP5/

What your CSS might look like:

```
/* hover nested element */
#parent:hover ~ div #child {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

The great thing is that `#konnichiwa` and `#konnichiwab`'s parent (or grandparent) would not need to be direct siblings with the general sibling selector (as they would need to be with the `adjacent sibling selector`).